# How do I stop a link changing color on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have an email link on my page that goes blue when hovered over.

I can't seem to fix this, i don't want it to change at all. In it's CSS i have it as:

```
.emaillink2
{   text-decoration: none;
color: white;}

a.hover:hover
{   text-decoration: none;
color: white;}

#headerinfo
{
float: right;
font-size: 32px;
color: white;
z-index: 1;
text-align: right;
margin-top: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The div's HTML:

```
<div id="headerinfo">
Telephone: 07777777777
<br/>
Fax: 07777777777
<br/>
Email: <a href="mailto:info@website.org" class="emaillink2">Info@website.org</a>
</div>
```

However it still changes color when hovered over.

Comment: Provide minimalistic sample on jsFiddle which reproduces your issue.

Comment: is the `.hover` class actually being added to the anchor??

Comment: Your hover attribute is not properly defined in css , change a.hover:hover{..} to a:hover{...}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change this code:

```
.emaillink2
{   text-decoration: none;
color: white;}
```

to this code:

```
.emaillink2, .emaillink2:hover
{   text-decoration: none;
color: white;}
```

Comment: Brilliant, fixed it, thanks a lot! (can't tick the answer for 9 mins but I will once I can :)

Comment: Why did you include "text-decoration: none" twice? It seems redundant in the first statement.

Answer (score 5):

Instead this

```
a.hover:hover
{   
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Use like this.

```
a:hover
{   
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but this won't work for me, I'd originally had it as this but a.hover:hover was suggested in another thread.

Comment: yes, because of provided answer will style all anchors within the document
but if you add a.hover:hover it will style only anchor elements which are with .hover class

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 'a' tags with different colours, you may want to try this in that case -

```css
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the color will change to the color of the surrounding text, not the `a{color: #;}`